# Regex to remove and preserve lines

Tags: php, regex, sed, code-injection, malware

I'm looking to use the following regex line to remove malicious code from my site;

`find -type f -name \*.php -exec sed -i 's/.*eval(base64_decode(\"CmVycm.*/<?php/g' {} \;`

This will preserve `<?php` which I want but I noticed that many of the injections are throughout php files on multiple lines, meaning not just the very first `<?php`   So is it possible to do an if do otherwise statement where if its on line 1 of a php file preserve the php tag otherwise remove the entire line if its anywhere else?

Comment: Does the malicious code begin with a specific string?  Does it always begin with `eval`?

Comment: No it begins with `<?php   eval(base64...etc`  but note that I have the syntax to preserve php there

Comment: Just restore your backup of the site code from before the attack happened. You do have a backup, right?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saying:

```
sed -i 's/.*eval(base64_decode(\"CmVycm.*/<?php/g'
```

say:

```
sed -i 's/eval[(]base64_decode[(]["]CmVycm.*//g'
```

This would preserve the `<?php` tag and also remove the malicious code from lines where the tag doesn't exist!

EDIT: As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693936/regex-to-remove-and-preserve-lines/18694379?noredirect=1#comment27540414_18694379) by [Birei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/773159/birei), you can say:

```
sed -i -e '1 s/.*eval[(]base64_decode[(]["]CmVycm.*/<?php/g' -e '2,$ s/.*eval[(]base64_decode[(]["]CmVycm.*//g'
```

Comment: No I dont think you understand.  The php tag exists for all instances of the code.  I want it to remove the php tag EXCEPT if its the first line, ie line number 1 in a php file.  The removal you provided works for preserving the php tag but it preserved it for the other instances too that were not on line number 1

Comment: `sed` can distingish between how to apply a substitution command to different lines. Use `1 s/...` for the first line and `2,$ s/...` for the rest.

Comment: @Scivic You don't need to worry about removing the PHP tag, you just need to remove the actual malicious code line, leaving a floating `<?php ?>` won't break anything.

Comment: Correct dave but the floating `<?php` does not end so it is throwing errors

Answer (score 1):

*The response from devnull isnt accepted, so here's mine*

If the malicious code takes one line, you can easily do :

`sed -i "/eval(base64_decode(/d" filename`

which will delete the all line.

if you worry about the first `<?php`

`sed -i -e "/<?php/! {1 s/^/<?php /}" filename`

It will add a `<?php` tag if it does not exist at the first line.
How does it work ?

`/<?php/!` will match lines without `<?php` in it.

`{1 s/^/<?php /}` In the first line, add `<?php` at the beginning

**More ?**

If the code takes 2 lines :

```
<?php
exec(base64_decode() ... ?>
```

`sed -i '/<?php/{N;/exec(base64_decode/d;}' filename`

If a line matches `<?php` and the next line matches `exec(base64_decode`, delete both lines.

`N;` is for loading the next line in the current buffer. `d;` delete the current buffer ( = both lines )

If the code takes 3 lines :

```
<?php
exec(base64_decode() ...
?>
```

`sed -i '/<?php/{N;/exec(base64_decode/{N;d;};}' filename`

Idem, but load the third line before deleting (`N;d;`)

**Not enough?**

Paste a full example of the string injected.

Hope this help, cheers